# Error creating related model instances in Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, mysql, orm, laravel-5.3, entity-relationship

I am just starting with a Laravel based project, and I am having problems creating a model instance related to another. In summary, I have a "Company" model class that references a "companies" MySQL table, and also a "Location" model class referencing a "locations" table. Both tables are related (a Company has many Locations, each Location belongs to a Company). So far so good.

I have a "Middleware" mechanism checking the existence of at least one company, and if there are no companies, I assume that is the first time running the system, so I display the "Create Company" controller/action so that the user creates the first company. On submit, this also creates a single Location record using the very same Company information, **so in the end the Location record in Database should have as "company_id" the ID of the Company record that was just created, But this is not happening**.

Let me display the existing files and classes relevant to this problem:

**Migration file to create the companies table:**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateCompaniesTable extends Migration {
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up() {
        Schema::create('companies', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('nit');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('contact_name')->nullable();
            $table->string('address')->nullable();
            $table->string('phone')->nullable();
            $table->string('email')->nullable();
            $table->string('website')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
            $table->integer('created_by')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->integer('updated_by')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->integer('deleted_by')->unsigned()->nullable();

            $table->foreign('created_by')->references('id')->on('users')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('updated_by')->references('id')->on('users')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('deleted_by')->references('id')->on('users')
                ->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->index('nit');
            $table->index('name');
            $table->index('created_at');
            $table->index('deleted_at');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down() {
        Schema::dropIfExists('companies');
    }
}
```

**Migration file to create the locations table:**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateLocationsTable extends Migration {
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up() {
        Schema::create('locations', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('company_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->string('nit');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('contact_name')->nullable();
            $table->string('address')->nullable();
            $table->string('phone')->nullable();
            $table->string('email')->nullable();
            $table->string('website')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
            $table->integer('created_by')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->integer('updated_by')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->integer('deleted_by')->unsigned()->nullable();

            $table->foreign('created_by')->references('id')->on('users')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('updated_by')->references('id')->on('users')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('deleted_by')->references('id')->on('users')
                ->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->foreign('company_id')->references('id')->on('companies')
                ->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->index('nit');
            $table->index('name');
            $table->index('created_at');
            $table->index('deleted_at');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down() {
        Schema::dropIfExists('locations');
    }
}
```

**Company model class**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

/**
 * App\Company
 */
class Company extends Model {
    use SoftDeletes;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'nit', 'name', 'contact_name', 'address', 'phone', 'email', 'website',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be mutated to dates.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    /**
     * Get the users for the company.
     */
    public function users() {
        return $this->hasMany(User::class);
    }

    /**
     * Get the locations for the company.
     */
    public function locations() {
        return $this->hasMany(Location::class);
    }

    /**
     * Get the invoices for the company.
     */
    public function invoices() {
        return $this->hasMany(Invoice::class);
    }

    /**
     * Get the user that created the record.
     */
    public function createdBy() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'created_by');
    }

    /**
     * Get the last user that updated the record.
     */
    public function updatedBy() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'updated_by');
    }

    /**
     * Get the user that removed the record.
     */
    public function deletedBy() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'deleted_by');
    }

    /**
     * Scope a query to only include the first active company.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $query
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
     */
    public function active($query) {
        return $query->orderBy('id')->limit(1);
    }
}
```

**The Location model class:**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

/**
 * App\Location
 */
class Location extends Model {
    use SoftDeletes;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'nit', 'name', 'contact_name', 'address', 'phone', 'email', 'website', 'company_id',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be mutated to dates.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    /**
     * Get the company that owns the location.
     */
    public function company() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Company::class);
    }

    /**
     * Get the products for the location.
     */
    public function products() {
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
    }

    /**
     * Get the inventory records for the location.
     */
    public function inventories() {
        return $this->hasMany(Inventory::class);
    }

    /**
     * Get the user that created the record.
     */
    public function createdBy() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'created_by');
    }

    /**
     * Get the last user that updated the record.
     */
    public function updatedBy() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'updated_by');
    }

    /**
     * Get the user that removed the record.
     */
    public function deletedBy() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'deleted_by');
    }
}
```

**The mentioned middleware to detect the first run of the system:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use App\Company;
use Closure;

class CheckSystemFirstRun {
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param  \Closure                 $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next) {

        /** @var \Illuminate\Http\Response $response */
        $response = $next($request);

        // The verification must be done AFTER the response has been generated, otherwise the request's route is
        // unknown.
        if ($request->route()->getName() != 'company.create') {

            // Check if there are no active companies.
            if (Company::count() == 0) {
                return redirect(route('company.create'));
            }
        } else {

            // Check if there are active companies.
            if (Company::count() > 0) {
                return redirect(route('dashboard'));
            }
        }

        return $response;
    }
}
```

**The CompanyController class which allows the user to enter the first Company and Location records:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Company;
use App\Http\Requests\AddCompanyRequest;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CompanyController extends Controller {


    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create() {
        return view('company.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param AddCompanyRequest $request
     * @param Company           $company
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(AddCompanyRequest $request, Company $company) {
        $company->create($request->all());

        // If there are no locations, create one using the same data as the received to create the company.
        if ($company->locations->count() == 0) {
            $company->locations()->create($request->all());
        }

        return redirect()->route('company.create');
    }
}
```

**The specified Request class that contains also the Company creation validations:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class AddCompanyRequest extends FormRequest {
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize() {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules() {
        return [
            'nit'     => 'required|max:255',
            'name'    => 'required|max:255',
            'email'   => 'required|email|unique:companies|max:255',
            'website' => 'url|max:255',
        ];
    }

}
```

When the database is brand new and I run the system, I am redirected to the "Create Company" action. On submit the new Company record is created successfully, but the expected location record is created WITHOUT the expected relationship with the Company record (company_id foreign key column keeps NULL).

[image: Company record successfully created]

[image: Location record created without the expected company_id value]

I am following [the recommendation from Laravel 5.3](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#inserting-and-updating-related-models) so I am not sure what is wrong with my code.

Before this question was posted, I found that the company_id field in the locations table may need to be defined as nullable in the migrations; it was not like that before, but back then Laravel/PHP responded an integrity error with MySQL because the "company_id" field cannot be null. I also tried to dd() the parameters used to define the company_id on the new record but the function returning the id value always returned null. Also, I have tried:

```
$company->locations()->create($request->all());
```

and

```
$location = new Location($request->all());
$company->locations()->save($location);
```

both without success.

I am using MySQL Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.10-MariaDB, for Win32 (AMD64) on Windows 10 x64, PHP 7.0.4.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

---

**Update 01**

Here is the output of the queries executed when the action is executed:

```
----------------------
Query: insert into `companies` (`nit`, `name`, `contact_name`, `address`, `phone`, `email`, `website`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Bindings: array (
  0 => '1113332323-9',
  1 => 'TEST COMPANY INC',
  2 => 'JOHN DOE',
  3 => '1362 36TH PL',
  4 => '8889990099',
  5 => 'test@test.com',
  6 => 'http://test.com',
  7 => '2017-01-16 00:16:25',
  8 => '2017-01-16 00:16:25',
)
Time: 4.5099999999999998

----------------------
Query: select * from `locations` where `locations`.`company_id` is null and `locations`.`company_id` is not null and `locations`.`deleted_at` is null
Bindings: array (
)
Time: 0.48999999999999999

----------------------
Query: insert into `locations` (`nit`, `name`, `contact_name`, `address`, `phone`, `email`, `website`, `company_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Bindings: array (
  0 => '1113332323-9',
  1 => 'TEST COMPANY INC',
  2 => 'JOHN DOE',
  3 => '1362 36TH PL',
  4 => '8889990099',
  5 => 'test@test.com',
  6 => 'http://test.com',
  7 => NULL,
  8 => '2017-01-16 00:16:25',
  9 => '2017-01-16 00:16:25',
)
Time: 4.5300000000000002
```

Comment: Aside from a few unrelated improvements, the location creation code looks right (I created a minimal example locally and `company_id` is assigned correctly). Can you check your query log and post the results?

Comment: Also you shouldn't need to have the FK column as nullable (unless you have a use case for a location without company) as `$company::locations()->create([])` should assign the correct fk value.

Comment: @ nCrazed, Please check the "Update 01" section in the main question contents. I just added the log output as requested. The insert query lacks of the company_id value. As for your comment about the nullable company_id, I agree with you. If I remove the nullable flag from the migration file and refresh, the mentioned process will generate an Integrity Violation exception because the Location record is being inserted without the required company_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the location to your ORM instance of `Company` on not the newly created record.

```php
$company->create($request->all());
```

should be

```php
$company = $company->create($request->all());
```

Comment: That is the answer. I though the create/save method would update the same $company instance without the need to assign it's result to the same $company variable. Thanks a lot.